# Delay when publishing a new GTM container version

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, web-analytics, web-analytics-tools

I am wondering how many hours does it takes to a new publishing version of a Google Tag Manager container to take in consideration the modifications ?

I tried to find the answer without result...

Thanks by advance for your help.

Coki

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does not take hours. Publishing a new container will immediately create a new gtm.js file with your changes.

New visitors will receive the new file immediately. Recurring visitors might have a cached version of the file, but then GTM sets http cache headers so that the file should not be cached too long. Some users (in company networks etc.) might sit behind proxy servers that cache and old version of the file.

But most users should receive the updated version of the file minutes after you have published it. I recommend you send the build in Container Version variable as a custom dimension to Google Analytics, so you can always check if changes in your KPIs correspond to specific container versions.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your complete answer.
Effectively, I am under company network and in consequences under a proxy that might cache the old version, it's why I don't see the changes.

Comment: Also bear in mind that if you distributed preview links or have set up different environments some users might still receive old versions - preview links do not update to the latest version (they refer to the version they were created for), and enviroments only update when you publish the latest version to them. But those should be edge cases.